# Django: Adding databases to DATABASES after startup

Tags: django, multi-tenant

So this is ultimately a multi tenancy question about adding new databases for new tenants after the server has started.  If i have an array of nodes behind a load balancer, i don't want to have to restart each one after a new tenant is created.  Since the database config has to be done in settings and settings is supposed to be immutable after start, how does one add databases dynamically?

Is there a proper dynamic way to add databases that django can use without having to restart the server?

Thanks

Comment: The question isn't clear. If you have an array of nodes behind a load balancer, from the point of view of your app they are just one database on one address.

Comment: @DanielRoseman that is correct, but for django you need to set up the database names and config in settings which i to me immutable after startup